# Ansible : How to loop over multiple variables in the playbook?

Tags: loops, amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm trying to write a playbook for implementing AWS Cloudwatch Status Check alarm on all EC2 instances. I tried hardcoding the 3 values (AWS_Name, Instance_ID & Instance_IP - Private) and its working perfectly fine for me. However, I need a solution to work ansible to work with the loop to get all the variables and create the Cloudwatch Status Check alarm for each instance one by one.

```
- 
hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: Create Alarm
      ec2_metric_alarm:
         state: present
         region: us-east-1
         name: "Status Check Failed - $AWS_Name - $Instance_IP"
         metric: "StatusCheckFailed"
         namespace: "AWS/EC2"
         statistic: "Minimum"
         comparison: ">="
         threshold: 1
         period: 60
         evaluation_periods: 2
         description: "This will alarm when the instance status check fails"
         dimensions: {'InstanceId': '$Instance_ID'}
         alarm_actions: ["arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:Cloudwatch-Notifications"]
```

Let's say I have 2 AWS instances, I can get the three variables which I mentioned above using AWS CLI query or manually. Now, I want to run the playbook only once to create the alarm for all 2 instances.

find the sample variables

```
  var1:
    AWS_Name: NAME1
    Instance_ID: i-01b8e4534wt811af4
    Instance_IP: "10.75.169.21"
  var2:
    AWS_Name: NAME2
    Instance_ID: i-4566eftuiw93045
    Instance_IP: "10.75.169.16"
```

Someone, please help me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running the task for `hosts: localhost` run it for `hosts: all_ec2_hosts` and [delegate](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) the task to `localhost`. So you can utilise the target hosts' variables in `ec2_metric_alarm` and don't have to run the task in a loop: `hosts: all_ec2_hosts` will spread the task to all hosts.

```
...
hosts: all_ec2_hosts
become: no
tasks:
  - name: Create Alarm
    delegate_to: localhost
    ec2_metric_alarm:
     name: "Status Check Failed - {{ inventory_hostname }}"
     state: present
     region: us-east-1
     ...
     dimensions: "{'InstanceId': '{{ ec2_id }}' }"
```

Obviously you'd replace `all_ec2_hosts` with a list of the target hosts or a host group.

`ec2_id` is a variable that's returned by the EC2 dynamic inventory script and contains the EC2 instance id.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable update. Is there any restriction on EC2 Dynamic inventory script for listing instances in ap-south-1 region (Mumbai). Have you had tried it before? B'coz, I'm not able to list instances in the same region.

Comment: This is already kind of off-topic but afaik there aren't any restrictions to AWS regions. Check regions and regions_exclude properties from your inventory/ec2.ini file.